# Insert foreign key data in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables.

A `product` table and another `product_image` table. A product can have many images and a product`s image can only have a single image.

So,

For `ProductImage` model

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
```

For `product` model

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductImage');
}
```

I have made foreign key relation using migration.

Now what I am unable to do is

I am trying to upload an image for specific product. how can I get the `id` of the `product` to insert in `product_id` of `productImage` table?

Comment: You have to insert product first. Get the product ID from there and use it while you are adding product images. _Bcoz, there won't be any images without product._

Comment: @RonakPatel ok I have a products page. After clicking on one specific product, user can see a add pic btn and when he clicks on that photo upload form shows up. Now when the user uploads the photo, the product id should also be inserted. If I attach the id of the product to the button for add photos it will be vulnerable, wouldn`t it?

Comment: you have to get product ID somehow. You can use one of the encryption methods and place it in hidden `input` tag in your HTML form. Then decrypt it before adding into the database.

Comment: @RajShakya please check the answers below, comment, voteup helpfull answers, and mark the answer as correct if it really hat you looking for.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki sorry, I got lost with other problems. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **[one-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)** relationship here, the relations between your models are true, i have just a small commentary for the function `image()` in your `product` model that should be pluriel `images()`.

Now for the implementation you have first to create a product and start to associate images to it, so like this you don't have to worry about `product_id`, you have just to use `associate` method that will set the foreign key on the child model, see example bellow :

```
//Creation of product
$product = Product::create(['Your attributes here']);

//Association of images
$product->images()->associate('Your image 1 here');
$product->images()->associate('Your image 2 here');
$product->images()->associate('Your image 3 here');

//To get the images associated with your product 
$product->images();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the exact result but it will help you to understand how to get last inserted id. example:

```
    <?php
    $product = new Product; //create the object

    $product->image= 'Your_image'; // image column 

    $product->save(); //store data

    //Getting Last inserted id

    $insertedId = $product->id;
    ?>
```